# discord.py how to assign roles to users v1.0 version

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import logging
from discord.utils import get
from discord.ext import commands
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def setrole(ctx, a: str):
    member = ctx.message.author
    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=a)
    await member.add_roles(member, role)
```

This is the code i use trying to assign roles to people entering the command. The role available in my server is rs6 so the code should be `!setrole rs6` but its not working.

```
Ignoring exception in command setrole:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruiyang(Harry)Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Workshop\example_bot.py", line 19, in setrole
    await member.add_roles(member, role)
  File "C:\Users\Ruiyang(Harry)Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\Ruiyang(Harry)Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 223, in request
    raise NotFound(r, data)
discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruiyang(Harry)Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Ruiyang(Harry)Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Ruiyang(Harry)Wang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10011): Unknown Role
```

I tried to do `print(role)` after line `role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name=a)`
and it printed rs6 which is correct. Someone please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a snazzy thing using command decorators. In the same way that you've set the type of arg to be a `str`, you can also set it to be a discord object:

```py
@bot.command() # Note that context is automatically passed in rewrite
async def setrole(ctx, role: discord.Role):
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
    await ctx.send(f"I gave you {role.mention}!")
```

You might want an error handler to deal with if the role isn't found:

```py
@setrole.error
async def _role_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send("I couldn't find that role!")
```

---

**References:**

- [`commands.BadArgument`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.BadArgument)
- [`Member.add_roles()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles)
- [Error handler per command](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Group.error)

Comment: @harry Glad to hear it! Good luck with the rest of your bot :^)